# Antonym of "distributed" as in "distributed system"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, computing

If we consider context of computing, what is the opposite of *distributed*? Is it *single* or *combined* ? What is the opposite of "distributed system"?

Comment: This question would be improved with more context.  Can you provide an example of a sentence where you would like to use this word?

Comment: -1 for lack of context. For all I know, OP could be asking about disaster relief agencies' stockpiles which have not yet been distributed to the people in need of them.

Comment: The opposite of [git](http://git-scm.com/) is [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/)

Comment: After 24 hours with no clarification from OP about the context, I'm voting to close as "not constructive".

Comment: At the systems level, the opposite of 'distributed' is 'integrated'. The recent edit of the question title from "opposite" to "antonym" muddies the water a bit, there being several types of antonyms. At the systems level, candidates for "antonym" include 'integrated', 'pooled' and 'converged'.

Answer (score 22):

In the context of databases and software applications in general, the antonym of distributed is **centralized**.

Comment: I agree - this is a better (or at least, more generically applicable) answer than mine

Comment: I have to disagree here. In CS terms, Distributed is generally used to mean across > 1 machines or files. Centralized is used to mean within the same organization, building or locality (Decentralized being opposite). As you can see here, a system (software, DB, hardware, etc) can be distributed and centralized at the same time. Source: I'm a CS Graduate that studied distributed systems for my Masters Thesis.

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon I disagree. In terms of graph algorithms, a centralized algorithm can be seen as one entity taking decisions having global knowledge of the given graph, whereas a distributed algorithm can be seen as all vertices of the graph taking individual decisions based on their limited local knowledge, accomplishing (or not) a global goal. The two seem to be opposites.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but I also disagree. In my mind "centralization" is precisely a strategy for distributing work.  A central "server" distributes work by dispatching it to "clients", who are all aware of the server's role as a central point of coordination.  This definition confuses the role of the database as a server with the distinction between a monolithic server and a distributed server.  Note:  "monolithic" is the best word I've got, but it isn't great...

Answer (score 4):

Probably depends on the precise situation, but for written technical use I would go with "co-located".
"Distributed" implies different *things* in different locations, where "co-located" implies different *things* in the same location. Both of your suggestions actually suggest only a single *thing* (in one way or another)

Answer (score 4):

Or perhaps an appropriate word is "localized."

Answer (score 3):

**Concentrated** is an antonym for 'distributed' from its connotation of 'spread out'.

Answer (score 2):

- Location: Distributed ↔️ Co-located
- Control: Decentralized ↔️ Central

I also wrote [a longer explanation](https://medium.com/plain-and-simple/decentralized-vs-distributed-1638c09f14e8)

Answer (score 1):

Some distributed computing frameworks [1] also use the term **single node** setup. This would match a context where distributed mainly refers to the fact that computation runs across multiple compute nodes. In this context, something like **local computation** might be appropriate as well.

[1] https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/203614/-what-is-cluster-single-node-cluster-and-node.html